# R: index-based apply to vector

Tags: r, vector, apply

Given:

```
original_vector <- c(2, 2, 2, 3)
indices <- c(1, 0, 0, 1)
```

I want to apply some function to `original_vector`, but based on `indices`. e.g. if the function is "increment by 5", my desired output would be `[7, 2, 2, 8]`.

I know how do this with a for-loop but I'd like to use something in the [apply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply) family.

There are similar questions, but they seem to be more complicated than my own usecase.

Comment: Do you have only a vector or want to do it in a list or data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use something from the `apply` family, consider `mapply` and provide both vectors. `mapply` and the custom function `my_fun` are taking two arguments: `original_vector` and `indices`.

```
my_fun <- function(vec, indices) {
  vec[indices == 1] <- vec[indices == 1] + 5
  vec
}

mapply(my_fun, original_vector, indices)
```

**Output**

```
[1] 7 2 2 8
```

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr` you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(original_vector, indices) %>%
  mutate(original_vector = ifelse(indices > 0,
                                  original_vector + 5,
                                  original_vector))
  original_vector indices
1               7       1
2               2       0
3               2       0
4               8       1
```